# How to clone global site-packages in anaconda?

Tags: python, installation, clone, anaconda, conda

Using `virtualenv`, I can inherit packages from the global `site-packages` directory using:

```
virtualenv --system-site-packages venv
```

I want to create a `conda` environment that is a clone of the global `site-packages`. I can only find documentation on how to clone existing *Anaconda* environments.